# How to push files modified by a pre-push hook on Git?

Tags: python-3.x, git, houdini

I have a Python script as a **pre-push** hook modyfing files inside my repo. Is there any possibility to immediately push those modified files as part of the same push?

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def sendUnpackedAsset():
    """Scan all .hdas available in the repo and unpack them."""

    hdas = os.listdir(
        f"{os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))}/otls"
    )

    for count, hda in enumerate(hdas, start=1):
        if hda.endswith(".hda") or hda.endswith(".otl"):

            print(f">>> Unpacking {count} digital asset(s)...")

            unpackAsset(
                unpacked_dir_name=f"{os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))}/otls/{os.path.splitext(hda)[0]}",
                source_hda_file=f"{os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))}/otls/{hda}",
            )

            if os.path.isfile(hda):
                print(f">>> Removing {count} digital asset(s)...")
                os.remove(hda)
```

It is modyfing binary files `.hda` or `.otl` contained in the repo, unpacking them to `.txt` files, and then removing the binary, leaving only the freshly created `.txt` files in the repo. Unfortunately, I need to push a second times to have those changes applied.

Comment: The short answer is no: a pre-push hook is invoked way too late to do that; the commits to be pushed are already chosen. The right place to do this is normally in a pre-commit hook and the right *way* to do it there is to *reject the commit* if there's something wrong with it, not to try to correct the commit. To get a smoother work-flow (with auto-adjusted commits), don't invoke `git commit` directly at all: run something else that adjusts and commits as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd have to git add any modified files and create a second commit, then push it all.

Comment: That's exactly what I was afraid of...